# Package installed in conda but module not found. How is that possible?

Tags: python, conda, modulenotfounderror

It seems that many people struggle with this problem, but I can't find any answer that works.
I think that I am doing everything right but it still doesn't work.
I've built my own package and installed it in my conda environment.
When I do `conda list`, it turns up in the list, at the end (I've called it zzpackagerps):

```
...
zlib                      1.2.11            h62dcd97_1010    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.9                h6255e5f_0    conda-forge
zzpackagerps              0.0.1                     dev_0    <develop>
```

Now when I run python, in this environment (py39), and try to import the package, I get the infamous ModuleNotFoundError:

```
(py39) s:\Sources>python
Python 3.9.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, May 10 2021, 22:10:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zzpackagerps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zzpackagerps'
>>>
```

How is this possible? Or, more importantly, how do I get this to work?
(by the way: running on Windows)

Comment: Are you sure that's the module name? Package names and module names don't necessarily agree.

Comment: Great suggestion, that's it!
The script's name (module) is different than the package name.
Importing the module works.
I think you could change your reply into an Answer.

Comment: @Reinier Can you elaborate on your response? I'm having the same issue but I didn't write the package in question. How did you import the module to get it working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible issue is that the package name may not be identical to the module name. If you locate the `site-packages` where the package is installed, you can try looking at the folder structure and where there are `__init__.py` files defined.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I discovered that my Conda env was not activated at the time that I installed the module. So I did "conda activate myenv",  before doing "conda install " again.  And this time it was picked up correctly.  If you are not sure which virtual env are available, use "conda env list" to list them.  The one with the asterisk beside it is the currently active env.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment so asking here.

Did you install the package as root? If yes, execute the following:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rX /home/deeplearning/anaconda3/envs/
```

If not, then it can be a Potential Path Problem:

Your python command might refer to a different python than the python which is in your active conda environment folder. Check this by running in the terminal `which conda` and `which python`.

Alternatively, reinstall conda.

Comment: No, not running as root. In fact, running on Windows (I'll edit my question to mention that, sorry). But not with admin privileges.

Comment: Did you double check the path?

Comment: What should the path be?  
It seems to me that activating the environment should make sure that all installed packages can be found.  
But for the record, there is no explicit reference in sys.path to the folder from where my package was installed.

Comment: just do ` where python` and check if the python path is inside your env path.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows users read this:

**When using the Anaconda prompt on Windows, type "python" instead of "py" to run Python** in the Anaconda environment with all your modules loaded. Typing "py" will run Python outside of the Anaconda environment. This is because, on Windows, typing "python" in the cmd will open the Microsoft store, so "py" is used as a shortcut to run Python from the command line.